# Соединение двух таблицы SQL и вывод последних трёх результатов

Tags: php, sql

Собственно, я новичёк в *PHP*, так что прошу тапками не бросаться. Есть две таблицы:

`users` и `review`.

В `review` поля: `id`, `from_id`, `from_name`, `from_avatar`, `content`, `note` и `to_id`.
В `users` много полей, главное поле - `id`. 
Задача такова: на странице профиля пользователя выводим все записи/последние три записи из `review`. Таблицы соединяем по полям `to_id` (в таблице `review`) и `id` (в таблице `id`).

Вывод происходит на странице пользователя: *profile.php?id=1*, где 1 - `id` владельца профиля. Несколько вариантов испробовал, самый близкий к результату был `INNER JOIN`, но почему-то он при выводе дублировал результаты несколько раз, а другие попытки приводят к тому, что выводится только первая найденная запись. Возможно, можно обойтись и без соединения таблиц, а просто сравнить `id` из строки и поле `to_id` из таблицы `review`?

Был бы благодарен за ответ с примером, по которому я смог бы ориентироваться. Интересует вывод последних трёх записей, сгруппированных по полю date (который я создам вскоре, т.е. чем свежее запись), как и всех записей.

Comment: Так Вам нужно последние 3 или все записи из review?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вообще делать Join?

Чем плох такой вариант?

```
SELECT * 
FROM review
WHERE to_id = :user_id -- пожалуйста используйте именно параметры
ORDER BY date_of_post DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте этот запрос

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users u 
  LEFT JOIN review r ON (u.id = r.to_id) 
 WHERE u.id = 'сюда подставляем id пользователя' 
 ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 3
```